# Strange Folder in /media/*myusername*/Ubuntu 16.04 LTS amd64

Tags: permissions, filesystem

Okay I'm pretty new to Linux and have some basic knowledge. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my laptop 250gb of / and I have several partitions which I'm not auto mounting. Recently I have noticed that there is a folder named Ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS amd64(exact same name as my distro) and when I try to open, it says

**This location could not be displayed**
*You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of “Ubuntu 
16.04.3 LTS amd64”.*

Which makes me worried is it fine to have a folder like that, please bear with me I'm new to Linux.

The output of `stat /media/gopi/Ubuntu\ 16.04.3\ LTS\ amd64`:

```
  File: '/media/gopi/Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS amd64'
  Size: 4096         Blocks: 8         IO Block: 4096 directory
Device: 802h/2050d   Inode: 13895877   Links: 2 
Access: (0700/drwx------) Uid: (    0/   root) Gid: (    0/   root)
Access: 2017-12-13 11:34:17.280834267 +0530
Modify: 2017-12-13 11:34:17.280834267 +0530
Change: 2017-12-13 11:34:17.280834267 +0530
Birth: -
```

And `findmnt /media/$USER/Ubuntu*` didn't return anything.

Comment: Add the output of `stat /media/$USER/Ubuntu*` and `findmnt  /media/$USER/Ubuntu*`, please.

Comment: How did you install your system? Maybe stupid question but is it possible that this is the installation medium still connected to the machine?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please use the [edit] function to include information into your answer, not use comments for that. I've included your information into your question for now and you can remove your comments. Thank you.

Comment: @derHugo I used an Ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS DVD to install, but after a week I again booted my computer with that DVD to resize my unallocated space using Gparted. Would it be the reason ?